# Issue with Conditional Logic - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having a problem with some conditional logic with Ruby. Admittedly I am a newbie to all things Ruby.

This code is causing the site not to load:

```
<body style="background-image:url("<%= if @is_home_page.present? '/images/bg-main-power-bg.jpg' else '/images/bg-inner-power-bg.jpg' end %>"); background-repeat:repeat-x;">
```

Without the conditional the CSS loads just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ternary operator for inline conditionals.

```
condition ? branch_a : branch_b

a == b ? "foo" : "bar"
# is the same as
if a == b
  "foo"
else
  "bar"
end
```

For your specific case:

```
@is_home_page ? '/images/bg-main-power-bg.jpg' : '/images/bg-inner-power-bg.jpg'
```

Comment: The variable @is_home_page will only exist on the homepage, with this work for that? Or do I need to use .present ?

Comment: @resonantmedia If an instance variable isn't set, it will equal nil and the ternary will still work. This does seem like a little bit of a code smell though.

Answer (score 2):

Your original code: The error you may be getting is probably due to the second `"` in this snippet `"background-image:url("<%= ...`. Try changing it so that the `<%= ... %>` is inside single quotes, not double quotes, since the whole string is already delimited by double-quotes.

Ideally you should strive to:

- Remove logic from view
- avoid inline styles.

So:

some.html.erb

```
<body class='<%= body_class %>'>
```

some_helper.rb

```
class SomeHelper
  def body_class
    @is_home_page.present? ? "has_homepage" : "no_homepage"
  end
end
```

some.css:

```
body.has_homepage
  background-image:url('/images/bg-main-power-bg.jpg')
  .......
body.no_homepage
  background-image:url(/images/bg-inner-power-bg.jpg')
  .......
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider moving this to a helper file. You could add the following to `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`

```
def bg_path
  return '/images/bg-main-power-bg.jpg' if current_page? root_path
  '/images/bg-inner-power-bg.jpg'
end
```

This leaves your view a bit cleaner.

```
<body style="background-image:url("<%= bg_path %>"); background-repeat:repeat-x;">
```

Reading: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F

Comment: My answer prevents the need for the `@is_home_page` variable altogether.